# How to enter information in a combo box with look up using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, combobox

I am having trouble with automating data entry in a combo-box with lookup/auto filling option element. The automation task is filtering data based on a company's name.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s2id_company_id']")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s2id_company_id']")).sendKeys(companyname);
    ((WebElement) driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

The script runs perfectly up until entering the data.

[image: Stopping Point]

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="div_ff_company_id" class="ff_item filter-field" data-type="filter-field" condition="company_id" operator="is_in" container="multi_select" type="default" data-label="Customer">

<label class="control-label">Customer</label>

    <div class="select2-container select2-container-multi input-xlarge filter_item" id="s2id_company_id" style="width:100%"><ul class="select2-choices">  <li class="select2-search-field">    <label for="s2id_autogen79" class="select2-offscreen"></label>    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen79" placeholder="" style="width: 10px;">  </li></ul></div><input type="hidden" id="company_id" style="width:100%" class="input-xlarge filter_item select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" value="">
```

Can you guys tell me if there is something I am overlooking?

Comment: Can you add the relevant html to your post?

Comment: @Grasshopper, thank you for taking a look. I am fairly new to scripting, so I am not sure what exactly is needed. What are some example of relevant HTML?

Comment: Right click on the combo-box and select inspect... Window will open up with the DOM details of the element. Copy and paste at least two levels above in your question.

Comment: @Grasshopper, Thank you!

Comment: Try this -- driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s2id_company_id']//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys(companyname);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clicking on it ... I mean after 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s2id_company_id']")).click();` statement then use

`WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement()`// which give the active or currently focused element.

Try #1 : `currentElement.sendKeys(companyname);`

Try #2 : inspect the element in Dom then use sendkeys

Try #3 : use `executeScript()` which takes function calls and raw JS, too. You can return a value from it and you can pass lots of complicated arguments to it.

For reference http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#using-javascript

Hope it helps

Comment: Ahh, yes. Try #1 worked! Thank you so much. Didn't realize it would be an active element issue given that the element was in use after clicking on it (or so I thought).